# How to design this table using latex? Table caption with background?

Tags: tables

Does anyone design this kind of table using latex?

[image: image here]

Comment: Welcome! What makes you think it was made with LaTeX? I certainly hope not! Either way, please post a small example document showing what you've tried. Start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so that we can reproduce whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Have you tried with `pgfplotstable`, `booktabs` and `colortbl` like in the `pgfplotstable` documentation ?
( http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf Section 2.3 "Configuring Row Appearance: Styles")

Comment: How automated should this be?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you. Following is my code.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}|}                                        \hline
\rowcolor{Cyan!100} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{TABLE 2.1 Terminology for Simple Regression}}} \\
\hspace{1.2cm} \textit{\textbf{y}} & \hspace{1.4cm} \textit{\textbf{x}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{Cyan!10}   Dependent variable & Independent variable          \\
\rowcolor{White!100} Explained variable & Explanatory variable          \\
\rowcolor{Cyan!10}   Response variable & Control variable               \\
\rowcolor{White!100} Predicted variable & Predictor variable            \\
\rowcolor{Cyan!10}   Regressand & Regressor                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Hope this will help. Here is my output,

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{colortbl}` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{sans}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\refstepcounter{table}\label{tab:mytab} 
\arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\rowcolors{3}{cyan!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}|}      \hline                               
\rowcolor{cyan} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Table\thetable. Terminology for Simple Regression}}}\\   
\centering\arraybackslash \textit{\textbf{y}} & \centering\arraybackslash\textit{\textbf{x}} \\ \hline
Dependent variable & Independent variable          \\
Explained variable & Explanatory variable          \\
Response variable & Control variable               \\
Predicted variable & Predictor variable            \\
Regressand & Regressor                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
From table \ref{tab:mytab}
\end{document}
```